# cannot connect to database in pgadmin using R

Tags: r, pgadmin

Wanted to try a simple thing.I created empty database in pgadmin. I used R to connect to that database but it`s not working. I searched it up online but could not get it working even though I have all packages installed.

code I used which I got it from a website.

```
# install.packages("RPostgreSQL")
require("RPostgreSQL")

# create a connection
# save the password that we can "hide" it as best as we can by collapsing it
pw <- {
  "new_user_password"
}

# loads the PostgreSQL driver
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
# creates a connection to the postgres database
# note that "con" will be used later in each connection to the database
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "postgres",
                 host = "localhost", port = 5432,
                 user = "******", password =******)
rm(pw) # removes the password`enter code here`
```

Am I missing something???

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: You could be using the wrong driver, or the right driver in the wrong location, or your credentials are wrong, or Postgres server isn't running.  You should give some error feedback.

Comment: R doesn`t show any error, and no changes in pgadmin even though server is active and I refreshed as well. How do I check i have correct driver, that seem to be the problem.sorry I`m new to this.

Comment: @neilfws @Tim Biegeleisen  , I`ll try redoing everything again and update.